# What do you call a metric space formed by taking an existing metric space and imposing a maximum distance?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

What do you call a metric space formed by taking an existing metric space and imposing a maximum distance?

Let $e$ be the Euclidean distance on $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$.

I'll define a metric space $S = (\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}, d)$ below.

Let $d$ be defined as follows:

$$ d(z, w) = \min(1, e(z, w)) $$

$d(x, y) = 0$ holds if and only if $x = y$.

The distance $d(x, y)$ is the same as $d(y, x)$.

The triangle inequality holds; I have a sort of convoluted argument below to show it.

---

This is the argument that shows that $S$ is a metric space. It's also where I first saw it; I was thinking about how to generalize metric spaces so I can encode information about the lengths of all paths between two points, not just the best one.

---

I'll define a metric space over a set $X$ as $X$ equipped with its distance function $d : X \times X \to \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0} \cup \{ \infty \}$.

The following axioms define metric spaces:

- $d(x, y) = 0 \;\;\text{if and only if}\;\; x = y$
- $d(x, y) = d(y, x)$
- $d(x, z) \le d(x, y) + d(y, z)$

I'll **nonstandardly** define a multimetric space as a set $X$ equipped with a distance relation $D : X \times X \times \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0} \to 2 $.

- Axiom 1: $D(x, y, 0) \; \text{holds} \;\; \text{if and only if}\;\; x = y$
- Axiom 2: $D(x, y, a) \; \text{implies} \; D(y, x, a)$
- Axiom 3: $D(x, y, a) \; \text{and} \; D(x, y, b) \;\; \text{implies} \;\; \exists z \exists c \mathop. D(x, z, c) \; \text{and} \; z \le x + y $

A multimetric space $M$ is associated with a metric space $\hat{M}$, which is obtained by defining the distance between $x$ and $y$ to be the infimum of $D(x, y, \square)$, and $\infty$ if $D(x, y, \square)$ is empty.

I'll **nonstandardly** define a pre-multimetric space as a set $X$ equipped with a distance relation $D : X \times X \times \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0} \to 2 $. However, this distance relation will only satisfy the first condition.

- $D(x, y, 0) \; \text{holds} \;\; \text{if and only if}\;\; x = y$

Given any pre-multimetric space $M$, I can define the "path closure" of the space by adding in all the $X \times X \times \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ hyperedges that are promised to me by axioms 2 and 3.

Okay, with that out of the way, here's the construction.

Let $M''$ be a metric space, $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ equipped with the Euclidean distance.

Let $M'$ be the pre-multimetric space by $D^{M'}(x, y, a) \; \text{holds} \;\; \text{if and only if} \;\; d^{M''}(x, y) = a$.

Let $M$ be the path closure of $M'$.

Let $P$ be a pre-multimetric space constructed by adding a new point $c$ to $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$. Additionally, let $c$ have distance $\frac{1}{2}$ from all points in $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$.

Let $P'$ be the path closure of $P$.

Let $P''$ be $P'$ with the special point $c$ removed.

Let $S$ be $\hat{P''}$.

Comment: I am unable to get beyond the word nonstandardly,

Comment: Is it too bold or did I describe the thing badly? I try to use `nonstandardly` if I'm making up a definition of something for a question.

Comment: I am just being a butthead :-).

Comment: The quantity $(,)=min(1,(,))$ appears in Munkres' "Topology", Theorem 20.1, under the name "$\bar{d}$, the standard bounded metric corresponding to $d$." The proof of the triangle inequality given there is straightforward and requires no "nonstandard" notions appearing in OP. I could not find what is the question in your post (other than the one which appears in the title).